# React-Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am having a react application with firebase as authentication. My authentication code is below

```
await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    props.setUser(user); //setting the user if login/register happens
                    history.push(`/admin/dashboard`);
                    console.log("user",user)
                } else {
                    props.setUser(null); //blocks the user to get into the app if he/she is not logged in
                    history.push("/");
                }
            });
```

So, when user logs in..he will be navigated to /admin/dashboard. suppose when am in /admin/home and when i refresh the page, it goes again to **admin/dashboard** which shouldn't happen. so I tried
**history.push(`${props.location.pathname}`);** it works correctly after the refresh, it stays on the same page when the application is logged in. but when I restart the server again when I try to log in, it says no redirect url is specified. Got stuck on this for a long time.. Any help is welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is check if the user is logged in and only let the user access the data if so.

You should do that in the fireabse rules (= serverside) as this is way more secure.
You didn't provide the kind of FirebaseDB you are using. So assuming you use the Realtime Database here are some according rules:

```
{
    “rules”: {
        “.read”: “auth != null”,
        “.write”: “auth != null”
    }
}
```

You should maybe check the rules before deploying your app, because now every authenticated user can change/add/delete data, but you get the point. This does exactly what you want so you won't even need to perform a check in your ReactJS App. Firebase will automatically deny unauthenticated users the access to the database.

Btw: You should try to implement security relevant things in the Firebase Rules. Ideally you want your rules to be written in a way that you don't need to perform any validation inside your ReactJS app. Firebase rules can get quite complex. I experienced that myself when writing a chat app with chatrooms and everything. But it is definitly worth the effort if your app is more secure after.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the answer?

Comment: Could the original poster please give some more information like what kind of Firebase Database is this (Storage, Firestore, RealtimeDB)?

Comment: i will try this and let you know..btw thanks for solution